# Custom usage of %w in Ruby

Tags: ruby, arrays

I know that `%w` or `%W` is used for constructing an array of strings. But I have a custom requirement:

Using `%w`, I would like to get the following array pattern:

```
["First Name", "Middle Name", "Last Name", "Email"]
```

Is it possible?

The space between the strings are making issues.

Thanks for any help offered :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll have to use character escaping to escape the space, like so:

```
result = %w(First\ Name Middle\ Name Last\ Name Email)
```

Though not sure if that reads any clearer than putting them in quotes.

Comment: Great brother!! Thank you for the rapid response.